# how to do multi-page run(app) in flutter?

Tags: flutter

am making an app and i want when i open the app if i logged in  it will open the home page but if iam not logged in then it should open the login page so i do that and it work but i am new at flutter and i think there is a good way to do it  but i dont know it so is there other way i can use or is this just fine to use ??

```
 main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
if (await pref.getToken() == null){
runApp(MyApp());
}else{
runApp(MyHomePage());

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the material widget initial Route. This will be more performance. The material widget has more extra property. You can take care of them too.

```
 main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Future getInitialRoute() async{
  var tokenIsExists = await pref.getToken();

    if (tokenIsExists) {
       return '/myapp';
    } else {
       return '/myhomepage';
    }
  }
  runApp(
   MaterialApp(      
     title: '',
    initialRoute:await  getInitialRoute(),
    routes: {
      '/myapp': (context) => MyApp(),
      '/myhomepage': (context) => MyHomePage(),
     },
     onUnknownRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => HomePage(),
                       ),
                     ),
                   );
     }
```

Comment: hi there  ,it causes a problem that the context in that way is a null , any idea how to insert the context in

Comment: @abed, You need to add routes, too. The answer is edited. Please check again.